# 80's-90's toy line- fighters move along string

Tags: story-identification, toys

My brother and I got these for Christmas when we were kids- space-age fighter type craft that moved back and forth along lengths of string that were fixed to furniture or along walls. Each craft had, in addition to spring-loaded rubber "missiles", cockpits that could be opened and shut and removable pilot figures that could hang from the string with 'lifelines'- string attached to plastic hooks. The hero's craft were colored bright yellow, the villain's were dark purple and grey.

Comment: When were you kids? And don't say *"before we grew up"*

Comment: @Valorum- this was between late 1980's early 90's, I said as much in the title.

Comment: https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1128198038108225&id=116745395026090 - ***Sky Commanders, where all the Action is above the ground!!!***

Comment: Each sold separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is likely Kenner's *Sky Commanders*.

Heroes have yellow vehicles:
[image]

You can see the string hook on the guy's arm.

Villains are purple and grey:
[image]